# Different nova.conf on each compute node for novnc acccess

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, nova

I have an enviroment with MAAS, Juju and Openstack Icehouse.

I have a nova-compute charm with three units (separate hw nodes).

Im using novnc web access for consoles of VMs.

This is done by writting in the nova.conf file

> > vncserver_listen = 0.0.0.0
> >
> > vncserver_proxyclient_ad​dress = [this_nova_compute_IP_addess]
> >
> > novncproxy_base_url =    http:// [nova_controller_IP_address]: 6080/vnc_auto.html

And the vncserver_proxyclient_ad​dress needs to be the IP address of the actual compute node as i observed right?

But the Nova.conf file is overwritten and maintained by Juju.

So how can i specify through Juju different IP addresses for different compute nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nova-cloud-controller and nova-compute charms added support to configure novnc, so you don't need to cook your own recipes :)

In a nutshell, just set console-access-protocol to novnc in nova-cloud-controller and you're done.

Take look to https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/nova-compute/+bug/1237996 for details about the implementation or http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms/trusty/nova-cloud-controller/config for configuration details.

Best,

Comment: Thank you. With Juno and new version of Juju i set up the parameter console-access-protocol at nova-cloud-controller charm and it works! Thank you!